# ReSharper API... Uh... where is it?

Tags: api, resharper

Ok I must be having a blonde moment, but for the life of me I can't find where to 
download the ReSharper API, to use with the project I got from [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/hadi_hariri/archive/2010/01/12/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-1-of-undefined.aspx).

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Part 2 of that series is out: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-2-of-n/

Comment: Are you referring to the actual assemblies? They are all located in the bin folder. The source code I published to github.com/hhariri

Also look at http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com

Comment: Got it I didnt' tweak that they were already sintalled here "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\ReSharper\v5.1\Bin" I was looking for a seperate API download on JetBrains.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Api information:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/open_api.html

You mostly need to reference various DLLs in the bin directory of the Resharper folder, then you can get started playing around.

If you don't have a license to the product, that would be an obvious prerequisite.

Edited to add:
Here's some ancient documentation, which may get you somewhere:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Introduction/openapi.html

And the developer forums:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_eap

And occasional tutorials on their blog:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/

It's not really great documentation, but you probably will have at least a little bit of help from Xml Doc comments.

Comment: I don't see any API documentation there though - the best appears to be 'read the source to the powertools' for the 4.x link on their confluence. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That was the info I Needed, Thanks! E-

Answer (score 1):

You can look at sources of [ReSharper PowerToys](http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/), open sourced examples of small features done with Open API.