# C#: How to programmatically determine which references are missing before manually compiling?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection

Here is the requirement: I want to create a custom visual studio C# project template, via which the created project has all references added correctly to pass compilation.

I got the problem that some references will be missing in this case: if the generated project contains code calling method `MethodA` of type `AClass` in a DLL named `A.dll`, but one of `AClass.MethodA`'s parameter is defined in `B.dll`.

**In short, `A.dll` references `B.dll` on method `MethodA` in class `AClass`, compilation will failed because of `B.dll` is missing.**

Anyone know the perfect solution on how to find the dependency of `B.dll` for compiling purpose?

I tried `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` but it will get all the referenced assemblies in which most of them are unnecessary.

I also tried to use `ReflectionResolve` event, but it won't help too.

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) handles this smooth as silk. A missing reference causes it to display an error in the source code window and it even suggests the correct dll to reference.

Resharper also has an [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304753/resharper-api-uh-where-is-it), if you want to code it yourself

Comment: Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Redgate .Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) might be a good choice. Though it is not free, but you can have a trial version for some days.

Click **Analyze** toolbar button, it will give you all the dll/assembly dependencies.

Comment: You mean I call API of "Reflector" to find the references for compiling purpose?

Comment: No, interactively do that. It is quicker.

Comment: but I want to do it `programmatically`, because it is a `custom project template`